# Some WordPress page links redirectinf to home page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, redirect

Links from the menu are directing correctly but links like the one in the page below are SUDDENLY not.

http://tazara.mwanawanga.com/?page_id=94

I gave searched on this topic. I have tried reseting permalinks and deactivating/activating plugins. Neither seems to work. I have also tried changing the theme. Still nothing.

Any helpful suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the form that does the redirect on that button. See below

```
<form method="link" action=" http://tazara.mwanawanga.com/?page_id=389">
    <input type="submit" value="View fare charts and train timetables">
</form>
```

If you can see, theres a space in the action field of the form which will error the form's action and go to the root.

Try changing it for this:

```
<form method="link" action="http://tazara.mwanawanga.com/?page_id=389">
    <input type="submit" value="View fare charts and train timetables">
</form>
```

The same will probably go for many other buttons on the site doing the same thing. I would personally recommend not using forms though and just creating a class which has the same styling as a form submit button and using `a` tags to link. It will be more search engine friendly and easier to use and maintain.

Comment: Thanks Stewartside. I removed the space, that didn't work. So I am using 'a' tags instead of form. The linking so far is working ok. I am just trying to see if I can get the styling right.